# Get HOST_ADDR in python without using external resource or webiste

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, django-rest-framework, django-settings

I'm working on a django project, how can i get my own public ip address without using any external websites, or **using python standard library**. I tried `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())` which returns `127.0.0.1`. As my project is hosted on different servers i want to configure my ***settings.py*** settings according to external IP. Any help.??